# yii2: how to use multi checklist value in one array variable

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Code from **_formCreate.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 height3">
  <p  class="col-lg-8">ورزشی</p>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'project_control_id[]')->input('checkbox', [ 'value' => '1', 'class' => 'col-lg-4'])->label('') ?>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 height3">
  <p class="col-lg-8">سرگرمی</p>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'project_control_id[]')->input('checkbox', [ 'value' => '2', 'class' => 'col-lg-4'])->label('') ?>
</div>
```

**Model** variable:

```
public $project_control_id;
```

Defined rules(){
    [['project_control_id'], 'string', 'max' => 5000],

My `$model` is not saved when I call:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'project_control_id[]')->input
```

but is saved properly in this case:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'project_control_id')->input
```

The question is why my model is not saved in the first case?

Comment: Try this  
http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-activeform-input-fields/#Checkbox-List-Input-Field

Comment: Correct spelling, indents and clarification.